# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() - Trouble playing Audio in a fragment

Tags: android, audio, static, fragment

So, I'm making an app with Scrollable Tabs + Swipe navigation.
In every tab's page I want to play a different audio file.

Below is my fragment's OnCreateView, containing initialization of the mediaplayer, FileDescriptor and playing an audio file named a.mp3 in the assets folder.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);


        ///Playing sound from here on 
             AssetFileDescriptor fda;
        MediaPlayer amp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {

            fda = getAssets().openFd("a.mp3");//// GIVES ERROR !
            amp.reset();
            amp.setDataSource(fda.getFileDescriptor());
            amp.prepare();
            amp.start();

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootView;

    }
}
```

The GetAssets() method gives an error as following :

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAssets() from the type ContextWrapper
```

Although this same piece of code from declaring the FileDescriptor to the final Catch Statement works perfectly in a normal blank activity's OnCreate. It's not working here.

Any solutions for this ?

Can I make the getAssets() method static somehow ?

Any other way to access the audio file from the Fragment ?

(Remember, my goal is to play a different audio file in each of the different tab's screens. I'll add more audio files later, Just trying to get at least this one to work first.)

Pls Help :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use a Context object, so in this example you could use:

`rootView.getContext().getAssets().openFd("a.mp3");`

That said, I would suggest moving this code later in the Fragment Lifecycle in `onActivityCreated` or `onStart` after the view hierarchy has been instantiated. Putting this code in `onCreateView` could delay/slow down showing the UI to the user.

From those later lifecycle methods, you can safely call:
 `getResources().getAssets().openFd("a.mp3");`

Comment: That did it :-) ... I'm probably going to have about 15-20 scrollable tabs with each screen containing a different audio file, image and some texts.... Any suggestions on how I can do this more efficiently, I reckon this might be too much for the CPU. Just wanna stay away from ANRs

Comment: At minimum, use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to handle your Fragments in your Viewpager. But, a GREAT way to do it - rather than creating a MediaPlayer in each fragment, maintain a SoundPool object in your Activity, and have each Fragment load into it/play from it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace getAssets() with context.getAssets() :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify following 2 method in your utility class. They return `AssetManager` for you:

```
public static AssetManager getMyAssets(Context context)
{
     return context.getResources().getAssets();
}

public static AssetManager getMyAssets(View view)
{
     return view.getContext().getResources().getAssets();
}
```

Now you can use them like this:

```
fda = myUtil.getMyAssets(rootView).openFd("a.mp3");
```

OR

```
fda = myUtil.getMyAssets(rootView.getContext()).openFd("a.mp3");
```